# Fix error in php

Tags: php, methods

After upgrade php to 5.5 this errors arose:

1. Strict Standards: Non-static method modIceNewsBlock::getImage() should not be called statically
2. Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$description

Please Help me to fix this errors

my code is

```html
<div class="ice-description clearfix">
     
        <?php if ($lShowImage): ?>
     <?php echo modIceNewsBlock::getImage( $item, $lImageWidth, $lImageHeight , $isThumb); ?>
        
        <?php endif; ?>
    
     <?php echo $item->description;?>

        <
    </div>
```

Thanks;

Comment: please check your class declaration.
it said the modIceNewsBlock::getImage()  should not be called statically

Comment: Try to print $item object and check the description is available or not . May be its missing or pointing the value is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If your method modIceNewsBlock::getImage() is static, you must declare it as static

```
public static function getImage() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    class modIceNewsBlock {
        // define a static function
        public static function getImage() {

        }
        // define a non static function
        public function nongetImage() {

        }

    }

    $modIceNewsBlock = new modIceNewsBlock();

    // to call getImage statically
    modIceNewsBlock::getImage();

    // to call function 
    $modIceNewsBlock->nongetImage();

    //you can check the variable $item if has values
    //
    var_dump($item)

?>
```